# How to crop image inside the path drawn using draw path on canvas,Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I am able to draw a rectangle using `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` commands on `Canvas`. What I want to do now is to crop the bitmap lying inside this square.

Here is my `onDraw()` method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawPath.moveTo(topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(topRight.x, topRight.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawPath.moveTo(topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(topRight.x, topRight.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y);
    drawPath.lineTo(topLeft.x, topLeft.y);
    canvas.clipPath(drawPath);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
}
```

If the `drawPath` is always a rectangle, you can use `Canvas.clipRect()`. Here is the same code rewritten using `clipRect()`:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
}
```

Comment: this is not working.It gives me whole bitmap not the just the area insde these paths. What i want is when I draw a path(lets say is a square) then resulting bitmap should have area inside these path(square) . Please help me out with dis ...its been 3days i m suck on this...

Comment: Try turning off the hardware acceleration. Hardware accelerated views do not support clipping properly. Read this if you need info about hardware acceleration: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Did turning off the hardware acceleration help?

Comment: @GareginSargsyan... Hey thanks for your solutions...i have not checked it yet as  currently i m working on something else...but soon i would have to complete this cropping module, sol will let you know then..